# Using a Video file as an Wallpaper

Tags: 15.04, video, desktop-background

I'm currently runing Ubuntu 15.04, and I would love to be able to put a video file (currently in webm format, but can be converted if neccesary) as my wallpaper. I am in love with the DreamScene feature Microsoft introduced (then brutally murdered) and i would love to have it on my Linux-Powered PC. If it's for any help, it's [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFZ8T.jpg) wallpaper.

I've already seen a lot of questions about how to put a video file as a wallpaper on ubuntu, but the answers were all outdated. therefore im asking it again for Ubuntu 15.04